# Access value in Subscribe's completed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am subscribing an Observable as follows:

```js
    this.service.post(request).subscribe(
        
        (value: Response> => { 

          // Do something with value

        },

        (error) => {
          this.state = State.Invalid;
          // Show errors on page
        },

        () => { 
          this.state = State.Completed;

          // Redirect to new page:
          this.router.navigate(['done'], { state: { v: value } });
        }

      );
```

Basically I am posting a request to an API and then I need to:

1. Do something with the returned value;
2. Show errors when an error exist
3. Redirect to new page when returned value is processed.

How to access value in completed? This is why I need to access it:

```js
      this.router.navigate(['done'], { state: { v: value } });
```

Should I move this line to the `next` function?

```js
   (value: Response> => { 

     // Do something with value
     // Redirect here

   }
```

Comment: When you subscribe to an observable, you get a stream of zero or more values via the 'next' callback. An observable's complete callback doesn't have a value. What value are you trying to access?

Comment: I made my question more clear with an update ... Does it help?

Comment: Yes, you can move it to the `next` callback, which will be called only if there is no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that within the `complete` callback directly, because it takes zero args.

If you want to access the value after both SUCCESSFUL and ERRORED, you can use `RxJS` operators, like the following:

```js
this.service
  .post(request)
  .pipe(
    tap((value: Response) => {
      // do something with the Response value here
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      // catch the error here, and return observable of anything that refer to an error not to the Response value.
      return of('ANYTHING_REFER_TO_ERROR');
    })
  )
  .subscribe((value: Response | string) => {
    // Here you can access the value,
    // which will be the Response value if there is no error,
    // or the value your returned from catchError.
  });
```

Comment: complete is called after Observable state is SUCCESSFUL or ERRORED? I thought it was only after NEXT

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer to include the solution using `RxJS` operators only. Thanks.